# Double click with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is this possible, to do double click when user clicks 1 time?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".colors-fake a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.catalog-inner').find('a.active').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    var index = $(this).index();
    $(this).closest('.catalog-inner').find('.colors a').eq(index).click();
});
});
```

Have this code, and I want to do double click when there is a single click on `.colors-fake a`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing so?

Comment: If your still having trouble or the answer did not answer your question let me know so I can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, simply trigger it like

```
$('myElement').trigger('dblclick');
```

or

```
$('myElement').dblclick();
```

See [dblclick()](https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/)